# Reverse Engineering Technique "Step by Step"

Tags: x86, reassembly

Sometimes, I see how someone puts on the github, some reverse engineering project for some famous game.

By researching these projects - I come to the conclusion that:
people just took the code from the **exe** and brought it gradually to an external **dll** - so they gradually tested the code.
In the end, from the main **exe** - they had only a small launcher and **crt**, and the rest of the place, of course, was filled with `nop` instructions.
They took out the code itself via copy / paste to **MASM**, and then, the resulting **COFF** obj-files, were added to the project with their new **dll**. (`code reuse`?)

I also have a game project in which I found 3 statically linked libraries in the exe.

Thus, I would also like to get acquainted with this technique in more detail and take it into my arsenal.

---

If any of you are very familiar with this technique, please share your experience.

Comment: I think it would be very useful if you could link an example repo

Comment: I found a thread on the KeeperFX forums with some information: https://keeperklan.com/threads/6854-Someone-explain-to-me-how-KeeperFX-was-done

Also:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130723043252/http://keeper.lubie.org/other_docs/change_exe_to_dll.htm